# Xamarin searchview OnActionExpandListener

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am struggling finding how to implement this Java code in Xamarin. 
I have tried `searchView.Close += delegate { };` but it doesn't work.

```
searchMI.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MenuItem#onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MenuItem#onMenuItemActionExpand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, it didn't work at first, I had an exception

> This is not supported use menuitemcompat.setonactionexpandlistener()

I had to do this instead

At the top of my file :

```
using MenuItemCompat = Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat;
```

In OnCreateOptionsMenu() when I create the search view.

```
IMenuItem searchItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.searchItem);
MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new ExpandListener(this));
```

And finally the listener class

```
class ExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListener
{
    Context context;

    public ExpandListener(Context pContext)
    {
        context = pContext;
    }
    public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
    {
        //MyStuff with context
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
    {
        //Stuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create custom class which implements `IMenuItemOnActionExpandListener`.

```
class ExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnActionExpandListener
{            
    public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then set listener to menuitem with

```
searchMI.SetOnActionExpandListener(new ExpandListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

`MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener` is not deprecated. So the solution for my `SearchView` was to first implement `IMenuItemOnActionExpandListener` in a new class :

```
  public class OnActionExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnActionExpandListener
  {
    public event EventHandler<IMenuItem> Collapse, Expand;

    public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item) {
      Collapse?.Invoke(this, item);
      return true;
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item) {
      Expand?.Invoke(this, item);
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Then in my activity :

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu) {
  MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.action, menu);

  var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
  var listener = new OnActionExpandListener();
  listener.Expand += (s, e) => {
    // ...
  };

  listener.Collapse += (s, e) => {
    // ...
  };

  item.SetOnActionExpandListener(listener);
  return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```